# WinGet COM Server is consuming 25% of cpu

Tags: windows-10, winget

last days i heard the laptop's fan kicking in, and i discovered a process called "WinGet COM Server" which is consuming CPU cycles. i uninstalled WinGet from apps, but it appearded once again. i think that windows update reintalled it.

curiosly i couldn't find posts about this issue

i'm using win 10 Pro 22H2 i don't want any processes consuming CPU as my laptop is an audio dedicated workstation

Comment: Have you tried to update WinGet, as that COM server, was replaced with something else awhile ago

Comment: I have the same issue since updating to Win10 22H2. I also can't end task on it.

Comment: I had the same issue (fans kicking in loudly due to high cpu usage) and noticed the same process. I didn't install any programs myself, but when checking the "Apps & features" pages in Settings a few minutes later, I noticed that "Windows Package Manager Source (winget)" was just installed or updated. It is an app by Microsoft Corporation and seems to get installed/updated automatically.

Comment: Regarding your remark about not wanting any processes consuming CPU, I don't think you have much control about that in Windows. If it's really that important for you, you should consider Linux instead. In my experience, also other update (background) processes in Windows can be quite noisy. Alternatively, you could try to update all software reguarly at more convenient times, in the hope that they won't arbitrarily kick in at unwanted times :-/

Comment: @wovano you are wrong, sorry. You are as much in control of what happens in windows as on linux. This is likely a bug as a lot of people are seeing it just now (after a winget update), after years of painless winget operation. Also, background update processes are not "noisy". Also, windows already strategically applies updates at convenient times, when you regularly don't use your computer. You don't even have to trigger it yourself. You shouldn't have too many background processes anyways (game launchers etc). I advise you stop making ill-informed comments about switching to linux like this.

Comment: Also, for reference, here is the github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/3667 . They had identified the problem and were working on a hotfix.

Comment: @pu239, I didn't say it isn't a bug, I said you don't have control over the Windows updates. If you know how to disable Windows updates (so I would not have encountered this bug), please let me know. And I know Windows tries to do its stuff at "convenient times", but the problem is that Microsoft does not know what is convenient for me. If I don't touch my keyboard/mouse, Windows will assume I'm "away from keyboard" so it can do some background maintenance tasks. But sometimes I'm still behind my pc and are bothered by the fan noise it causes. I don't think there's much we can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using WinGet, try killing the process in taskmgr, which will stop it using any CPU cycles at all. If it still appears, see if there is a WinGet task in Task Scheduler that restarts it (although maybe not if you have uninstalled it).
If it keeps coming back you might have to write an automated batch file (automate it with Task Scheduler) that contains

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im (WinGet COM Process Here)
```

You might be able to avoid it restarting, but I don't know how
Hope this helps

Comment: Instead of constantly stopping the process when it restarts, you might better avoid the "restartings".

Comment: Any ideas on how...

Comment: @e7eth - Supposedly this behavior was solved with an update to winget